# Lookup from time series panda dataframe

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pandas, data-science-model

I have below reference table with date time series defined in 20 mins interval

```
    DateTime            Bucket  DayOfWeek   DayofMonth  StartTime   EndTime
0   2018-07-19 06:00:00 NaN      5            19    2018-07-19 06:00:00 2018-07-19 06:20:00
1   2018-07-19 06:20:00 NaN      5            19    2018-07-19 06:20:00 2018-07-19 06:40:00
2   2018-07-19 06:40:00 NaN      5            19    2018-07-19 06:40:00 2018-07-19 07:00:00
3   2018-07-19 07:00:00 NaN      5            19    2018-07-19 07:00:00 2018-07-19 07:20:00
4   2018-07-19 07:20:00 NaN      5            19    2018-07-19 07:20:00 2018-07-19 07:40:00
```

How can I lookup from above table for each time in below table, which is  between starttime and endtime of above table?

```
                  time  tollgate_id direction
1   2018-07-19 06:11:53         2   0
2   2018-07-19 06:13:54         2   0
3   2018-07-19 07:17:48         1   0
4   2018-07-19 07:16:07         2   0
```

Expected output table would be,

```
                 time   tollgate_id direction datetime              dayofweek
1   2018-07-19 06:11:53         2   0         2018-07-19 06:00:00     5
2   2018-07-19 06:13:54         2   0         2018-07-19 06:00:00     5
3   2018-07-19 07:17:48         1   0         2018-07-19 07:00:00     5
4   2018-07-19 07:16:07         2   0         2018-07-19 07:00:00     5
```

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Data Science SE! Such questions get better answers on StackOverflow. The exact same question has an answer there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125626/pandas-merge-with-logic

Comment: Thanks. Link was the perfect solution for this.